# How to stretch the middle view vertically in a ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have two TextInputLayouts as a header and a footer in my XML layout, and a RecyclerView in between. What I wanna achieve is to set the height of the RecyclerView to fill the area between the other two.

I've tried setting constrains of the RecyclerView based on the header and footer and setting layout_height to 0dp, but it seems there's a problem. The RecyclerView gets crushed to 0 pixels in runtime.

Here's my code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilSearchTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_search">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvTitles"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation"
        android:paddingVertical="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tilTitleValue"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tilSearchTitle" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilTitleValue"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:hint="@string/str23"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/col_deep_bg"
        app:counterMaxLength="30"
        app:counterTextAppearance="@style/CounterStyle"
        app:expandedHintEnabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <com.zeroone.mooyrag.customui.MyTIET
            android:id="@+id/tietTitleValue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/iransans_med_fa"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parent ConstraintLayout height should be `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`.

Comment: `0dp` is fine actually, wrap content of container is the issue of recyclerview being "squashed".

Comment: Yes you are right , will edit my answer, Thanks!